# CSS from third-party library, using CSS modules, is loaded in after rendering in nextJS

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, next.js, css-modules

I created a new nextJS (v14) project using the app. Most components and styling will be done by an external React component library which is installed with npm. This library is styled using CSS modules. Whenever I load a page from my application, I see a flash of unstyled content on the components coming from the external library. All other styling (even those coming from CSS modules in the project itself) are applied correctly. I don't know if relevant, but the page in the nextJS project uses "use client".

When I inspect the code, I see that the styles are added to the  too late (approx 1 second after the render of the page).

Is it possible to immediately add the styling of these external components to the page source or if not just let nextjs pause it's rendering until all styles are applied? Or what would be the appropriate solution to mediate this problem?